# Why are Japan and South Korea two topmost lobbyist in the USA?

Tags: united-states, japan, lobbying, south-korea

Why are [Japan and South Korea two topmost lobbyists in the US](https://www.opensecrets.org/fara)A?

What do they mostly do lobbying about?

I understand other countries' concerns, but what are the agendas of Japan and South Korea?

Comment: They're big exporters.  Japan, esp. in the 80-90s, often was getting whacked with import duties or "voluntary" Japan->US self-limitations in cars.  Makes sense they'd want to wine n dine congress folk.  I'm surprised China's so far down that list, except that it might  not be totally to a congress person's best image to be seen hobnobbing with them right now.

Answer (score 2):

Trade, mostly.  Lobbying to make it easier for Americans to buy Japanese goods.

Japan's registered lobbyists include various trade organisations, and individual companies looking for access to the US market. These countries come at the top because they are rich and do a lot of business with the USA.

Individual lobbyists might have specific concerns,  Eg NHK, (Japanese broadcaster) lobbies regarding Japanese language education (for Japanese children in the US)